# Reassigning Entries in a Column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

My goal is to conditionally index a data frame and change the values in a column for these indexes.

I intend on looking through the column 'A' to find entries = 'a' and update their column 'B' with the word 'okay.

```
group = ['a']

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [a,b,a,a,c], "B": [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]})
>>>df
   A    B
0  a  NaN
1  b  NaN
2  a  NaN
3  a  NaN
4  c  NaN

df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x in group)]['B'].fillna('okay', inplace=True)
```

This gives me the following error:

SettingWithCopyWarning:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)

Following the documentation (what I understood of it) I tried the following instead:

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x in group)].loc[:,'B'].fillna('okay', inplace=True)
```

I can't figure out why the reassignment of 'NaN' to 'okay' is not occurring inplace and how this can be rectified?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with lambda:

**Solution First:**

```
>>> df
   A   B
0  a NaN
1  b NaN
2  a NaN
3  a NaN
4  c NaN
```

Using `lambda` + `map` or `apply`..

```
>>> df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: "okay" if "a" in x else "NaN")
OR# df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: "okay" if "a" in x else np.nan)
OR# df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'okay' if x == 'a' else np.nan)
>>> df
   A     B
0  a  okay
1  b   NaN
2  a  okay
3  a  okay
4  c   NaN
```

**Solution second:**

```
>>> df
   A   B
0  a NaN
1  b NaN
2  a NaN
3  a NaN
4  c NaN
```

another fancy way to Create Dictionary frame and apply it using `map` function across the column:

```
>>> frame = {'a': "okay"}
>>> df['B'] = df['A'].map(frame)
>>> df
   A     B
0  a  okay
1  b   NaN
2  a  okay
3  a  okay
4  c   NaN
```

**Solution Third:**

This is already been posted by @d_kennetz but Just want to club together, wher you can also do the assignment to both columns (A & B)in one shot:..

```
>>> df.loc[df.A == 'a', 'B'] = "okay"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I realised that the question I asked didn't fully capture my problem, however, your first solution still worked.

'group' should actually contain multiple items.

Comment: If it helps then you can accept it as a answer and open a new question with new set of queries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you simply want to replace the value for a column on those rows matching a given condition (i.e. where `A` column belongs to a certain group, here with a single value `'a'`). The following should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

group = ['a']

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a','b','a','a','c'], "B": [None,None,None,None,None]})
print(df)
df.loc[df['A'].isin(group),'B'] = 'okay'
print(df)
```

What we're doing here is we're using the `.loc` filter, which just returns a view on the existing dataframe.

First argument (`df['A'].isin(group)`) filters on those rows matching a given criterion. Notice you can use the equality operator (`==`) but not the `in` operator and therefore have to use `.isin()` instead).

Second argument selects only the 'B' column.
Then you just assign the desired value (which is a constant).

Here's the output:

```
   A     B
0  a  None
1  b  None
2  a  None
3  a  None
4  c  None
   A     B
0  a  okay
1  b  None
2  a  okay
3  a  okay
4  c  None
```

If you wanted to fancier stuff, you might want do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

group = ['a', 'b']

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a','b','a','a','c'], "B": [None,None,None,None,None]})
df.loc[df['A'].isin(group),'B'] = "okay, it was " + df['A']+df['A']
print(df)
```

Which gives you:

```
   A                B
0  a  okay, it was aa
1  b  okay, it was bb
2  a  okay, it was aa
3  a  okay, it was aa
4  c             None
```